# Ubuntu Upgrade from 20.10 to 21.04 or 21.10 not possible

Tags: server, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I currently have the problem that I cannot update from Ubuntu 20.10 to 21.04 or 21.10.

My Ubuntu Version:

```
Distributor ID:Ubuntu
Description:Ubuntu 20.10
Release:20.10
Codename:groovy
```

I would like upgrade to next higher verson, but still not work, following steps were done:

1. Set Archive Package

   ```
   sudo sed -i -re 's/([a-z]{2}\.)?archive.ubuntu.com|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Upgrade Packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
3. Reboot OS
4. `sudo do-release-upgrade`

   Output:

   ```
   Reading cache

   Checking package manager

   Can not upgrade 

   An upgrade from 'groovy' to 'impish' is not supported with this tool. 
   === Command terminated with exit status 1 (Thu Mar 24 07:30:42 2022) ===
   ```

Workaround:

Not work:
https://www.barryodonovan.com/2022/01/31/upgrading-legacy-versions-of-ubuntu

same Issue

Attention:

I have only Ubuntu Commandline without gtx Display output.
Ubuntu are Cloud Azure VM

Comment: Correct. There is no method to go from 20.10 ⇢ 21.04 ⇢ 21.10 anymore. You will need to install 21.10 overtop your existing installation. [This answer from many years ago](https://askubuntu.com/a/20668/1222991) can offer more details on the situation 

Comment: You can re-install desktop systems without losing data files, having your Ubuntu repository *manually installed* package re-installed automatically, allowing you to achieve a change of release - however as system directories are wiped during this install; a location where many server apps store configs; it's not *great* with server installs. Ubuntu 20.10 told you it was the 2020-October release with 9 months of supported life; it wasn't difficult to plan the *release-upgrade* before 21.04 reached EOL (you had 6 months).  If you don't like regular *release-upgrades* you should have used a LTS